# Add more lines in title of the slide

Tags: beamer, themes

In LaTeX Beamer presentation, in the first slide, how to add address line?  Below is my code line which I am using for making first slide (Title). After the date command line, I would like to add the address line.

I have used there breaking line command `\\` , but which I typing there it is appearing in the top corner of the slide, but I want it after institute name.

```
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title[Climate Impacts Research Centre]{CIRCs'Activities}
\subtitle{38th annual Meeting}
\institute[]{\Climate Impacts Research Centre}
\date{June - 2017}
\would like to add one more line for adress of the institute
\author[38th annual Meeting]{SWAT and Jhon}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This help?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\title[Climate Impacts Research Centre]{CIRCs'Activities}
\subtitle{38th annual Meeting}
\institute[CIRS]{Climate Impacts Research Centre\par\bigskip
\inst{1} Somewhere University\par
\inst{2} Another university} 
\date{June - 2017}
\author[38th annual Meeting]{SWAT\inst{1} and Jhon\inst{1}}
\titlepage  
Would like to add one more ?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. One more issue, how to add \textbf command line only applicable for this line {Climate Impacts Research Centre ? And specific color (Green) for that line

Comment: @SWAT `\textcolor{green!40!black}{\textbf{Climate Impacts Research Centre}}`